# Excel time difference over 24 hours

Tags: excel, time, duration

We have a process that shouldn't go over 24 hours (it did) and I have simply been copy/pasting the times from the reporting system i.e. 00:01:05 to 01:23:38 and simple subtraction to give me hours/minutes/seconds duration.

Excel is fine if this is the same 24 hour period, but those two times are split by 24 hours. As you can gather the copy/paste is not including dates so how do I trick excel into adding another 24 hours.

I've read quite a few options out there but none of them seem to work, or its just my 2020 brain....

Comment: If you have the date, use that. If not, then you don't have enough info: describe your algorithm you want to use.

Comment: One possible algorithm: If the sign is wrong, add 24h. If that doesn't give the results you want, describe the algorithm that would give the proper results.

Answer (score 1):

So long as the interval will never be equal or greater than 24 hours, you can use:

```
=end-start+(start>end)
```

If it might be => 24 hours, then you will need to add date information.